Magnon driven effects
Linear spin wave theory is the standard framework in the diagonalization of the Heisenberg model. From the seminal works, I understand that LSWT predicts spontaneous ferromagnetism and magnon-magnon scattering.
I was wondering which observable predictions can be or have been made using Heisenberg's model and higher-order Holstein-Primakoff transformations. I have been googling for a while and did not satisfy my curiosity. I have seen some examples in Stancil's Spin Waves book, but I still don't see how a spin wave can produce anything else than a finite-Temperature demagnetization.
Shortly, I am looking for answers like: "this effects is a spin wave consequence and can be predicted from LSWT (or higher orders)". Thank you
